# Xero application limits

Tags: xero-api

Xero documentation says:
"Each API response you receive will include the X-DayLimit-Remaining, X-MinLimit-Remaining and X-AppMinLimit-Remaining headers telling you the number of remaining against each limit."

How do I access these limits? When I make a call for a balance sheet for example:

```
Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Model.Accounting.ReportWithRows pal = await apiInstance.GetReportBalanceSheetAsync(accessToken, xeroTenantId, startDate, 1, timeFrame, null, null, true, false).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The returned json document does not have any limit information.  I Googled that some headers need to be included.  Is there a c# code example on how to get those headers?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't say how you'd access it via the API, but in the response from a raw http call in VB, the headers are in response.headers. I had a quick look through the API but I can't follow it easily enough.

Comment: I need an example of code in c#.  Perhaps there are some Xero developers out there.

Comment: To get the headers for say the account endpoint you could just use `curl -I -X 'GET'   'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Accounts'   -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Xero-tenant-id: `<tenant-id>`'  -H 'Authorization: Bearer `<access token>`'`  (you need to have an valid access token obviously too).